# Solve $\int_{|z|=5} \frac{z^2}{(z-3i)(z-3i)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

> Solve$$\int_{|z|=5} \frac{z^2}{(z-3i)(z-3i)}.$$

So I am currently working on the unit about the Cauchy Integral Formula, where$$\int\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}=2\pi i f(z_0).$$

The zero $z=3i$ lies within the circle $|z|=5$ so $z_0=3i$ and we can rewrite the integral so$$\int_{|z|=5} \frac{\frac{z^2}{z-3i}}{z-3i},$$where $f(z)=\frac{z^2}{z-3i}$. However, when I attempt to plug $z_0$ into $f(z)$, the denominator is zero which is definitely wrong.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Thank you for providing context and your attempts. Now, have you learned the Residue theorem? The thing is, you cannot use Cauchy here, because your $f(z)$ is not analytic (still has a simple pole at $3i$, even after dividing out by $(z-3i)$).

Comment: The pole is a second order pole.

Comment: I have not learned the residue formula, but I will look into it! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is this generalization of Cauchy's integral formula that you can apply here: under the same conditions as Cauchy's integral formula, you have, for each $n\in\Bbb Z_+$,$$\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_{|z-a|=r}\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}\,\mathrm dz=\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}.$$So, take $n=1$ here. Of course, with $n=0$ this is just the standard formula.

Comment: So here would it become $\frac{f'(a)}{1!}$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.